# Compare value of 2 SELECT boxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 2 HTML SELECT boxes (id=Select1 and Select2). I would like to have jQuery compare the value of Select2 against Select1 after an onChange event of Select2.

If Select1 and Select2 have the same value then clear the value in Select2 or reset it and then a simple javascript alert window?

I am a PHP developer and pretty much a noob with jQuery so any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Nothing yet, not positive on the syntax of jQuery yet so didnt put together any functions. Looking into it now.

Comment: Well, you should attempt solving it yourself before you ask a question here.

Comment: @Felix, I am attempting to do it myself while also coming to Stackoverflow. If your unwilling to assist just ignore the post unless you have something constructive to contribute. Thanks

Comment: As per the FAQ's, Felix is totally within reason to tell you to attempt it yourself before asking.  Hover over the "down-vote" button to see the description about _"showing any research effort"_.  Also, snippy attitudes will get you nowhere here.

Comment: Research effort is clearly different than having any code written. I understand the basic flow and even some of the functions I would need as I mentioned above, see ref to onChange event, etc.. (thanks to research) but because I had no code written it was assumed there was no effort which was incorrect. 

I will take your advice and clearly state exactly what "research" was done. Thanks

Comment: What about when "select1" is changed to the same value as "select2"?

Comment: @Ron, good point, building that check into it now.

Comment: Here's a selector that includes both id's: $("[id^=select]").change(...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#Select2").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == $("#Select1").val()) {
    alert('Duplicate value');
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#select2').change ( function () {
    if ( $('#select2').val() == $('#select1').val() ) {
         alert ( 'do whatever');
    }
});
```

Take a look at [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Will it work with a space between `change` and `(`?  Even if it does, it seems pretty superfluous.  Also, why not use `$(this)` within the function?

Answer (score 1):

**Full working example:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Select2').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == $('#Select1').val()) {
                alert('same');
            } else {
                alert('different');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <select id="Select1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="Select2">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```